# How do you use 的 at the end of a sentence

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

Like for school my teacher gave us an example 看足球赛的学生. And she wanted us to do that format. Such as the music I like or students who are doing homework at school So is it the thing the subject is doing 的 and then the subject.

Answer (score 4):

看足球赛 is a complete sentence

Adding adjective marker "的" after a sentence or phrase turn it into an adjectival phrase.

Adjectival phrase describes the noun that follows.

[Simple phrase]: 看足球赛 = watch football match

[Adjectival phrase]: 看足球赛(的) = (those who) watch football matches

[Adjectival phrase with subject]: 看足球赛(的)学生 = (those/ the) students (who) watch football matches

*Since 看足球赛的 is an adjective, you can follow the grammar structure of [subject + is + adjective] and write 
"那些学生 是 看足球赛的" (those students are the ones who watch football matches)*